# Print out info on other page, in exact place

Tags: php, html

I want to create a Gallery with a databse. Connect to database, use `foreach` to print out info in prepared `HTML` code.

I separated the `PHP` code from the `HTML` code, so **each type of code** is in **different folders**, separated files, for example, i have `index.php` which requires `html/index.html` and runs all the necessary code.

Now im facing a real problem - how can i output prepared `HTML` code in exact place? It's impossible to use `foreach` and `echo` without writing `PHP` code between `HTML` lines, right ?

Comment: Use a template system like smarty, don't invent that wheel again. Separation of logic and presentation is the correct way, having implemented the basics of such a system is a good exercise, but the corner cases, additional functionality needs that will inevitably crop up make using an existing solution the best way.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a lot of template engine on the wild web like Blade, Deval, HAH, mTemplate, pHAML, PHP, RainTPL, Scurvy, Simphple, Smarty, StampTE, TinyButStrong, Tonic, Twig, uBook ..., just pick one according to your needs.

Comparison between them can be easily found with a simple search on "php template engine comparison"

Here, by exemple, a [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_template_engines) with a quite complete list by techno.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19193907)

Comment: Yes you're right, the answer is edited with more content.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use some framework, like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/), [Symfony](https://symfony.com/) or [Phalcon](https://phalconphp.com). They all have big community and good documentation with a ton of examples. Besides, they all come with their own templating system and use their preferable [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) system. This will help you to make your code clean and elegant, or at least cleaner, then if you tried to invent your own wheel.